# Nesting if/else statement in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

This is a text adventure game. The user is faced with the first scenario `a()`. If they choose 2, the game continues. If they choose 1, they die and are presented with the option to play again. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
"""
MAIN LOOP
"""
play_again = "yes"
while play_again == "yes" or play_again == "y":
    a()  # user makes a choice
    choice = choose_ans()
    check_ans_a(choice)  # intention: if user chooses "1", they die and are asked to play again
        if choice == "1":  # problem: Unexpected indent. If indent is deleted, b() becomes unreachable
            play_again = input('Play again?\n'
                               '(y)es ')
            break
        else:
            continue
    b()
    choice = choose_ans()
    check_ans_b(choice)
```

EDIT: The solution, derived from comments below, was simple:

```
"""
MAIN LOOP
"""
play_again = "yes"
while play_again == "yes" or play_again == "y":
    a()  # user makes a choice
    choice = choose_ans()
    check_ans_a(choice)
        if choice == "1"  # player dies
            play_again = input('Play again?\n'
                               '(y)es ')
            continue  # restarts loop
    b()
    choice = choose_ans()
    check_ans_b(choice)
```

Comment: What makes you think `b()` is unreachable if you delete the indent?

Comment: that's what pycharm is telling me

Comment: fix the indent and then delete the `else:continue` statement. The `continue` statement tells python to ignore everything below and go back to the `while`

Comment: Why there is extra indentation before `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `else: continue`. If the code enters the `if` block, it will `break` out of the `while` loop. But if the condition isn't met, the `else` block will be entered. Inside a `while` loop, `continue` will automatically go to the top of the loop and start again, which is why `b()` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the continue. Continues makes the code "jump" to the start of the while loop again. Suggestion: delete the else/continue part. If there are only these two options it's not needed. If a==1 the break will leave the while loop. if its 2 a==2 is not True therefore the part after it (b) will be tested.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_continue_statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try run this version of your code for debug purpose, comment/uncomment to see how the result changes. I used random to simulate the user input getting rid of the method calls.

```
import random

play_again = "yes"
while play_again == "yes" or play_again == "y":
    choice = random.choice(["1","2"])
    print('choice = choose_ans()', choice)
    if choice == "1":
        play_again = random.choice(["yes","no"])
        print('play_again?', play_again)
        # break # <-- the break control is already made by while condition
    # else:
    #     continue
    # b()
    choice = random.choice(["1","2"])
    print('check_ans_b(choice)', choice)
```